# Do we need to add 에 to this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I saw this example online where "Sam went to Korea last year in October during the autumn season" was translated to "샘 은 작년 10월 가을에 한국에 갔다". May I ask if we need to add a '에' after 작년 10월? Why or why not? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"샘은 작년 10월에 한국에 갔다."
"샘은 작년 가을에 한국에 갔다."

Both sentences are just natural.
and the using "-에" means "in", "on", "at".
But if you repeat to use, it sounds like unnatural.

"샘은 작년 10월에 가을**에** 한국**에** 갔다."

We might don't use like this in English.

```
"Same has been in Korea **in** Autumn **in** last year October.
```

And you can replace "-에" into "-중" or "-중에"

```
샘은 작년 10월 중에 가을에 한국에 갔다.
```

At the same time. You can use this.

```
샘은 작년 10월에, 가을에 한국에 갔다.
Sam has been in Korea in October last year (which is) fall.
```

If you add "," mark it's natural, and none of weird.

Answer (score 1):

### `~에` used with `갔다/왔다`.

- It is okay to remove `~에` when it clearly tells where; what place you went to.
- But if `~에` is about the time when that action was done, it cannot be ommitted.

---

For example:

> 1. 가을에 한국에 갔다. -> Nice

- `I went to Korea in Autumn.` written in the most canonical form.

> 2. 가을에 한국 갔다. -> OK

- This is still a correct sentence. But it's spoken in an extremely casual tone.

> 3. 가을 한국에 갔다. -> Wrong

- This doesn't make sense because it means that the person went to a place called `가을 한국` rather than `he went to Korea in Autumn`.

---

Also there's [a similar question](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=216&qna_seq=142107) answered by 국립국어원.